# Grep for python try except pass anti pattern

Tags: grep, python

I am trying to grep for various python coding anti patterns, so that they can be caught during our builds. I am having a hard time utilizing grep to do the match over new line.

Anti pattern to search for:

```python
except:
  pass
```

The below patten works great in Intellij, but does not work when applied with grep.

```
except:\s+pass
```

Please recommend on how to achieve this.

Comment: This is old, but may still be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep#2686705

Comment: just use `pylint`

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse structured data like source code is the MOTHER of anti-patterns.

Comment: By the term `grep` you mean Shell (Bash, Sh, Ash, etc.)? If so, edit the TAGs in your query because there is also a Shell and at least modify the term "grep" to "grep command in the Shell (command-line)". If you mean system Shell, then there are many solutions (awk, sed, grep, printf, using python interpreter, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `pcregrep` which stands for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions GREP.

```
pcregrep -M "^except:\n\s+pass$" file
```

where `-M, --multiline` allows patterns to match more than one line.

The regular expression matches the literal `:except:` at the beginning of a line followed by a line break, 0 or more white spaces (matching the most amount possible) and by the literal `pass` at the end of the line.

Comment: @iruvar See my updated answer.